# Django test client - sendng POST data returns 400 error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, post

I have problem with writing tests for Django (just started with this framework). Everything works flawless in browser, but when I'm using TestCase, it seems that request method is not POST. Here's the code:

views.py:

```
def save(request, quiz_id):
    try:
        quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=quiz_id)
        qset = Question.objects.filter(quiz=quiz_id)
    except IndexError:
        raise Http404
    questions = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = QuizForm(request.POST, qset)
        if f.is_valid():
            do_stuff()
            return render(request, 'quiz/results.html', {'questions': questions})
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

tests.py:

```
def test_results(self):
    post_data = {
        'ans10': 43,
        'ans6' : 28,
        'ans7' : 33,
        'ans8' : 36,
        'ans9' : 38,
    }
    resp = self.client.post('/1/save/', post_data)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

And running test:

```
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200
```

Form is valid, passed data is correct, in browser, like I said, everything works. I have just problem with this test, it seems like request method is not POST. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: In file everything is OK ;) But I'll fix.

Comment: What's the url pattern?

Comment: As an aside, `get_object_or_404` might raise `Quiz.DoesNotExist`, but it's never going to raise `IndexError`.

Comment: @KrastamanRastamarian : I indeed assume your source file is correctly indented - at least "correctly" enough for not raising a SyntaxError. The point is : _we_ don't have access to your source file.

Comment: You should return, or at the very least log, the errors in the case that `f` is *not* valid. And you might want to show us the code for `QuizForm`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell given your broken indentation, but it seems your view will only return a 200 if it's a POST request **and** the form is valid.  Could it be that your form doesn't validate ?

This being said, the recommended flow is to return a redirect to the result page on successful posts (google for "post redirect get") to avoid double submissions on page reloading.

Totally unrelated but none of the statements in you try/expect block will raise an IndexError, and if `Question` has a ForeignKey on `Quizz` you should be able to retrieve questions directly with `quizz.question_set.all()`.